# create URL slugs for chinese characters. Using PHP

Tags: php, regex, slug, non-ascii-characters, chinese-locale

My users sometimes use chinese characters for the title of their input.

My slugs are in the format of `/stories/:id-:name` where an example could be `/stories/1-i-love-php`.

How do I allow chinese characters?

I have googled and found the japanese version of this answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506016/trying-to-generate-url-slugs-with-php-regex-japanese-characters-not-going-throu).

Don't quite understand Japanese, so I am asking about the chinese version.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using wordpress ?

Comment: I am not using wordpress. I am writing my own webapp using PHP.

Comment: please provide sample url with Chinese characters for my testing & checking:

Comment: i have given a solution, u may try...

Answer (score 9):

**i have tested in Bengali characters**

it may work. try this:
at first the coded page (write code where in the page) have to convert into encoding type in UTF-8, then write code.

**code here:**

```
function to_slug($string, $separator = '-') {
    $re = "/(\\s|\\".$separator.")+/mu";
    $str = @trim($string);
    $subst = $separator;
    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
    return $result;
}

$id=34;
$string_text="আড়াইহাজারে দেড় বছরের ---  শিশুর -গলায় ছুরি";
$base_url="http://example.com/";
echo $target_url=$base_url.$id."-". @to_slug($string_text);

var_dump($target_url);
```

**output:**

```
http://example.com/34-আড়াইহাজারে-দেড়-বছরের-শিশুর-গলায়-ছুরি

string 'http://example.com/34-আড়াইহাজারে-দেড়-বছরের-শিশুর-গলায়-ছুরি' (length=136)
```

Comment: sorry to bother you but your regex also allow unknown characters such as @#!!?-=+ , is there any way to allow chinese word but also at the same time prevent the unknown character