# Jquery validation, japanese number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to allow user only japanese numbers input for mobile field?
disabled other input.

Comment: http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO thread has almost exactly what you need.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284335/how-to-do-jquery-validation-to-allow-only-english-and-japanese-characters-in-the)

In short, you use Regex to validate that only Japanese characters were used. You can use jquery.validate.js or write it all out yourself.