# Coldfusion doesn't recognize japanese character unicode when searching with regular expression

Tags: regex, unicode, coldfusion

When try to search japanese characters with regular expression in Coldfusion, I got this code.

```
<cfset test1 = REFind("[\u3040-\u309F]", "あ")> (1)
<cfset test2 = REFind("[\u61]", "a")>           (2)
<cfdump var="#test#">
```

With `(1)` I got the result `0` that indicates there is **no** match. But actually, the above unicode matches **all** hiragana characters including the above char `あ`. It should return `1`.

With `(2)` I got `1` that indicates it matched.

I also tried with all ANSCII chars, it works but japanese chars doesn't.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787716/regular-expression-for-japanese-characters