# Regex to match Japanese/English texts

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to have a regular expression rule that matches to texts where 1. has Japanese characters (= English only text is not allowed) 2. can have English (alphabetical) characters 3. can have other arbitrary common symbols such as `-,.。、！!?？@＠・'’0-9`.

The following meets 1. has Japanese characters, but not 2 and 3.

```js
var regex = /^[^\p{Script=Hiragana}\p{Script=Katakana}\p{Script=Han}\p{Script=Katakana_Or_Hiragana}\p]+$/
"パイソンが得意です".match(regex) // matches
"pythonが得意です".match(regex) // does not match
"I'm good at python.".match(regex) // does not match
```

The problem is that, the following still doesn't meet 2, 3, while I expected it to meet the all of three.

```js
var regex = /^[^\p{Script=Hiragana}\p{Script=Katakana}\p{Script=Han}\p{Script=Katakana_Or_Hiragana}\pA-Za-z\s'\.]+$/
"パイソンが得意です".match(regex) // matches
"pythonが得意です".match(regex) // still does not match
"I'm good at python.".match(regex) // still does not match
```

So, what's the problem to fix the regex rule?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787716/regular-expression-for-japanese-characters . please check this if it helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need the `u` flag to use `\p{}`. Second, there's no script named `Katakana_Or_Hiragana`. Third, add everything you permit in a single character class.

Get those three right, then add a lookahead to ensure that there is a Katakana/Hiragana/Kanji in the input string:

```
^
(?=.*[\p{Script=Hiragana}\p{Script=Katakana}\p{Script=Han}])
[\p{Script=Hiragana}\p{Script=Katakana}\p{Script=Han}a-zA-Z-,.。、！!?？@＠・'’0-9 ]+
$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RnAUtQ/1).